# SSIS - IF AND STATEMENT

Tags: ssis, ssis-2019

how can this if and statement be written in derived column.

```
IF(AND(AD2>-1,AD2<16),"0-15 Days",(IF(AND(AD2>15,AD2<31),"15-30 Days",(IF(AND(AD2>30,AD2<91),"30-90 Days",(IF(AD2>90,"90+Days",AD2)))))))
```

how can this be written in derived column

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SSIS Installed in my Machine. So didn't tried.
But you can write something like this

IF(AND(AD2>-1,AD2<16),"0-15 Days",(IF(AND(AD2>15,AD2<31),"15-30 Days",(IF(AND(AD2>30,AD2<91),"30-90 Days",(IF(AD2>90,"90+Days",AD2)))))))

```
AD2>-1 && AD2<16 ? "0-15 Days" : (AD2>15 && AD2<31 ? "15-30 Days" : (AD2>30 && AD2<91 ? "30-90 Days" : ( AD2>90 ? "90+Days" : AD2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column is called AD2 then:

```
AD2>-1 && AD2<16 ? "0-15 Days" : AD2<31 ? "15-30 Days" : AD2<91 ? "30-90 Days" : "90+Days"
```